# TableView: method editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

which editingStyle i have to use to have the result of this tutorial?

[Table View Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html)

I would like have a editingStyle without "-" or "+". If in the method editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath i return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone i don't have "-" (for delete) or "+" (for insert) but i have my table's rows shifted to right e with blank space.

In the apple's tutorial there is not the blank space before of the rows's content.

What is the way to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the row to be editable and you don't want the row indented when the table view is in edit mode, then indicate that the rows can't be edited by returning `NO` from the `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` data source method. Of course you need to return `YES` for the index paths that can be edited but return `NO` for the index paths that can't.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (/* this index path can be edited */) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this way can i drag & drop rows?

Comment: That is a completely separate question from editing. You need to implement the `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` method to indicate whether a row can be reordered or not.

Comment: Ok ok, I will try it as soon as possible. Thanks Rmaddy!

Comment: I have tried. If i return NO to canEditRowAtIndexPath for every rows i can't move rows in the table. I have implemented also method canMoveRowAtIndexPath that returns YES for every row. How can i do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve my issue I have implemented this `UITableViewDelegate` method

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
```

that for every row of my table `returns NO;`

Thanks to all.